# How to make fopen remote request with referral?

Tags: php, fopen

I want to download a remote file from a server which uses hotlink protection, I think, I get the download file download via curl and the use fopen to save the file but not possible as url has 301 redirects for remote site homepage which actually works fine if referred by example.com.
Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try to set the referral URL with cURL?

Comment: Study this: https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/